# urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 32] Broken pipe - Google Leads

Tags: python, google-api, urllib2, google-ads-api

I'm trying to upload a file to Google via the Adwords API and I'm using the script provided by Google here:https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib

I'm getting the following error after a few minutes.  I've tried this on a smaller file and it works.  Not sure why it is breaking here.  Any ideas?

```
  File "./g_leads.sh", line 71, in <module>
    main(adwords_client, EMAILS)
  File "./g_leads.sh", line 43, in main
    response = user_list_service.mutateMembers([mutate_members_operation])
  File "/opt/stateadm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleads/common.py", line 296, in MakeSoapRequest
    for arg in args])
  File "/opt/stateadm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 521, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/stateadm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 581, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
  File "/opt/stateadm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 613, in send
    reply = self.options.transport.send(request)
  File "/opt/stateadm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/transport/https.py", line 66, in send
    return HttpTransport.send(self, request)
  File "/opt/stateadm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 82, in send
    fp = self.u2open(u2request)
  File "/opt/stateadm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 132, in u2open
    return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1215, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1177, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 32] Broken pipe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Errno 32 Broken Pipe means the remote server closed the socket. I would guess the transfer is taking too long because the API documentation shows that they would return an error if the file itself is too big.

Conversely, this may be a intermittent issue at Google per [this old thread.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adwords-api/RRdOkkBdiTE/hDQNxcbafvgJ)